# Move /home to new partition on CentOS

Tags: centos, partition, home-directory

I have a new partition which is called /dev/DTX and I would like to move /home to it. /home contains all users websites. Is there any way to do it via SSH?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why use ssh for this? You have new partition on the same machine that actual /home (am I right?). So all you have to do is mount new partition copy all files from /home. Then umount /home and remount new partition as /home. (Maybe I mis understood your question and you dont want to copy files via ssh only do all tasks remotly via ssh then  yes you can do it via ssh).